# Error INSERT INTO records wrong my sql syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert values from python into a mysql database using a web hook.   However when I run it I get the error:

> "Error: INSERT INTO records ( timestamp, tensor, float1, int1 ) VALUES ( '1521860398', '1', '2', '3' )
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int1 ) VALUES ( '1521860398', '1', '2', '3' )' at line 6"

My php code looks like this:

```
<?php
if($_GET["token"]=="oSImm4M9ke52QhovmmqeFgpDS0dKTirwV5") {

#If Statement to get a token from TFLearn
#IF Statement to make sure all the data is set
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "Chip15334";
$password = "Chip1214";
$dbname = "code_output_metrics";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

#Put in a PHP database call

#Use a PHP "GET" from the data being passed from the dataset and then     add it to a database row]

$timestamp = time();
$tensor = $_GET['tensor'];
$Float1 = $_GET['Float'];
$int1 = $_GET['int'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO records
(
timestamp,
tensor,
float1,
int1
)
VALUES (
'$timestamp',
'$tensor',
'$Float1',
'$int1'
)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

} else {
    echo "wrong token";
}
?>
```

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-I

Comment: @Strawberry delete vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following are reserved keywords in mysql. You can't have a column called `int1`.

```
Reserved word => Synonym
INT1          => TINYINT 
INT2          => SMALLINT 
INT3          => MEDIUMIN 
INT4          => INT 
INT8          => BIGINT
```

https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,569810,572087#msg-572087

Comment: ...and so, the solution is to use backticks.

Comment: @mickmackusa I advise against it. Use a different variable name.

Comment: You should explain your recommended solution in your answer.  (There is nothing wrong with wrapping it with backticks.)

Comment: I think he's smart enough to recognize my recommended solution when I say *you can't have a column called int1*. I didn't say there's something wrong with backticks. I said I advise against it. I appreciate your input, but I'm satisfied with my answer. If you're not, you have every right to downvote me.

Comment: You are accurately identifying what is wrong, but you aren't providing a solution.  You mustn't assume the knowledge level of the OP and thousands of future researchers that may visit this page.  StackOverflow questions are not a 1-to-1 interaction.  Every answer becomes part of the greater knowledge pool.  Please put the best into every answer that you post with the intent to educate.

Comment: I didn't say anything about his knowledge level. I said he's smart enough, and I was being sarcastic, because the notion that he needs to be told explicitly is preposterous. A 12-year-old kid would make the leap just as readily.

Comment: I was trying to be helpful.  I can see you are unwilling to improve your answer, so I'm gone.

Comment: It took you this long to figure that out? I told you way back that I'm satisfied with my answer. Maybe you were unable to infer that I had no intention of changing it? Now I understand why you think other people need things spelled out. They don't.

Comment: Thanks that worked well